# include directory in php

Tags: php, directory, dir

How do I include the directory in my file??

My folders goes something like this like this

```
/require/connect_database.php
/ajax/anotherfolder/myfile.php
```

Let say I opened one of my file on `ajax` folder (`ajax/anotherfolder/myfile.php`)

How do I include the file from the `/require` folder in my `myfile.php`?

I've tried something like this, but it didn't work.

****myfile.php****

```
include '../require/connect_database.php';
```

Comment: Where is `require` in relationship to `myfile.php`?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing one `../`. You have:

```
/ajax
    /anotherfolder
        /myfile.php
/require
    /connect_database.php
```

To get from `ajax/anotherfolder/myfile.php` to `require/connect_database.php`, you need this:

```
include '../../require/connect_database.php';
```

Comment: Great! Please remember to accept this answer when you can. :)

Comment: I will, I have to wait 9 more minutes to accept the correct answer